# Eclipselink + JPA generates ID column unexpectedly

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

Eclipselink generated a create table statement like so:

```
Create Table myTable (ID (255) not null, col1 (255), col2(255), col3(255) PK (ID, col1, col2)  



@Embeddable  
MyPK implements Serializable  
{  
    @OneToOne  
    @Id  
    String col1;  

    @OneToOne  
    @Id   
    String col2;    
...  
}  



@Entity  
MyClass implements Serializable  
{  
   @EmbeddedId  
   MyPK pk;  
   String col1;  
   String col2;  
   String col3;  
...  
}
```

How do I prevent the generation of the `ID` column in the `Create Table` statement?  I ask because `em.persist(MyClass)` throws a constraint exception on `ID` being null.  I expected that the `@EmbeddedId` would override this and prevent that field from being created.

*EDIT*
The table that I am trying to generate in code looks like so:

```
fk - col1  
fk - col2
VarChar  - col3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue is a String attribute can not be a OneToOne mappings.  Second a OneToOne mapping can not be used within an EmbeddedId.  Third you do not use the @Id annotation within an EmbeddedId as an Embeddable can not have identity.

The easiest way to do this is:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(MyPK.class)  
MyClass implements Serializable  
{  
   @OneToOne
   @Id
   TargetClass rel1;

   @OneToOne
   @Id
   SecondTargetClass rel2

   @Basic
   String col3;  
...  
}

MyPK implements Serializable  
{  
    String rel1;  

    String rel2;    
...  
}
```

If you really need an Embeddable for the pk class then replace the @ID annotation with @MapsId and add the EmbeddedId annotation back in MyClass and the Embeddable annotation back to MyPK

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what was necessary